# How to restore free Space after deleting virtual machine disk?

Tags: kvm, qemu, manjaro, btrfs, libvirt

Hello everyone i wish you all doing good.

---

So lately i was working on a **Manjaro 21.2.5** host on latest updates  with a **Windows 11** guest Vm running on **qemu/kvm** with **libvirt** and a **dynamique size virtual disk**, after installing some heavy software in in the guest(Win 11) i noticed my **disk space is full** and i only have 14mb free space, so i deleted the Vm with libvirt's GUI and then i noticed the **i did not get my free space back** and i corfirm that **i deleted the virtual disk**. And the used host partition for Vm is formated in **Btrfs**.

---

Thank you so much every one.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main ways disk space is not released with btrfs on Linux:

1. The file you deleted is still open.  This is not specific to btrfs, but most Unix-style operating systems in general. Linux allows you to keep working with a file which is deleted.  It will be fully freed when the last user disappeared.  I'm not sure if deleting the vm with libvirt is prone to this.  You can check if this is the case with:
   `lsof full/path/imagefile`
2. btrfs did not have a chance to release the blocks just yet. It can take some time, but generally not more than minutes.  In case you have already run out of disk space, this background operation may also disturbed.  You can try running `btrfs fi sync .` in the directory the image file existed, and if it does not help, you may need to remove other files and run a balance operation.

In some rare cases, you may need to use the `-musage0` and/or the `-dusage0` options (for two separate commands) first to create space for a "real" balance operation, such as:

```
btrfs balance start -musage=0 .
btrfs balance start -dusage=0 .
btrfs balance start .
```

3. Finally, it's possible that you have a btrfs snapshot on the same volume, which means the state of the volume is kept safe, so no matter how many files you remove, the snapshots will still refer to the file you want removed.  In this case you will need to remove the snapshots (and consider what else you may be removing with them).  Check the `btrfs subv list .` and `btrfs subv del (snapshotname)` commands.

Comment: Thank you so much i really appreciate it ,but after so much searching i haven't found a good solution and i needed the computer that time, so i formated it and i am now on fedora it going nice. and for the solution the 3 one might be the one i needed i tried 1 and 2 solution and no hope so thank you so much ur the best <3.